# smarty template - passing javascript variable in url

Tags: php, javascript, smarty, fullcalendar

I am new in smarty template
I have added calendar, I just want to pass the date of calendar to other page.

For example:
When a user clicks on the `24-12-2012` date then I need a url like in this format:
`eventpost.php?ed=24-12-2012``

I have calendar.tpl file:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var myJsDate = date;
        var dispDate = myJsDate.getDate() + '-' + (myJsDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + myJsDate.getFullYear(); // 24-12-2012
        var det = dispDate
        $("#currentDate").val(dispDate);
        $('#offDayPopUp').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 180,
            draggable: false
        });
        $('#calmonth_' + myJsDate.getMonth()).addClass('cal_month_active');
    },
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="offDayPopUp" class="offDayDialog" title="Create Event,Commitment,Visiting Area.">
    <div class="CrateDiv">
        <div style="float:left; padding-right:10px;"><b>Date :</b></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="currentDate" id="currentDate" readonly="readonly" /></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{$cfgRoot}/event/eventPost.php"><b>Create A New Event.</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="{$cfgRoot}/commitment/commitment.php"><b>Create A New Commitment.</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="{$cfgRoot}/area/areaPost.php"><b>Create A New Visiting Area.</b></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want to pass that date from JavaScript to url like:

```
eventPost.php?ed=24-12-2012
commitment.php?ed=24-12-2012
areaPost.php?ed=24-12-2012
```

Comment: Why don't you add the date over PHP? That'd be way more easy and faster.

Comment: php not work in tpl file. how can i add php code between {literal}{/literal} function

Comment: you can write php code between {php}{/php}

Comment: @danishhashmi i know but how? can you please explain because when i take {php} in javascript then javascript represent this as javascript code

Comment: you need to end {literal}javascript code {/literal} start {php} php code then end {/php} {literal} javascript code {/literal}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following danish hasmi's possibility to use PHP, better use PHP like this. Javascript isn't meant to be used for data manipulation that can be done serverside.

```
//[...]
<li><a href="{$cfgRoot}/event/eventPost.php?ed={php}echo date('d-m-Y',mktime());{/php}"><b>Create A New Event.</b></a></li>
//[...]
```

See [mktime on php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php) to adjust the mktime-parameter and set it on your wanted date.

**//Update**

Even though it makes more sense to use PHP, this is how you'd do it in Javascript for your sake.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var myJsDate = date;
        var dispDate = myJsDate.getDate() + '-' + (myJsDate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + myJsDate.getFullYear(); // 24-12-2012

        $(".CrateDiv > ul").find("li").each(function() {
           var atmhref = $("a",this).attr("href");
           $("a",this).attr("href",atmhref+"?ed="+dispDate);
        });
        //...
```

Comment: i dont want to pass today's date..
as per my question i want to pass any date which is in calendar

Comment: I added the possibility to set it to a wanted date.

Comment: no, i just want to pass that javascript value behind the url.

Comment: just one problem with that code. when i click on the 1st box the date appear in URL is fine. but when i click on the 2nd box then the date is appear two time....for ex.... 1) eventPost.php?ed=19-12-2012  (this is ok but 2nd time).... 2) eventPost.php?ed=19-12-2012?ed=20-12-2012. (previous date not clear) if possible than pls help me how to clear the previous date....Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,You can use onclick event and pass the selected date using Javascript function

```
<script>
 {literal}
 function golink(type) {
   var selecteddate = $("#currentDate").val();
   if(type=='event'){
       location.href="http://www.mysite.com/event/eventPost.php?ed="+selecteddate;
    }
   if(type=='commitment'){
       location.href="http://www.mysite.com/commitment/commitment.php?ed="+selecteddate;
    }
  if(type=='area'){
       location.href="http://www.mysite.com/area/areaPost.php?ed="+selecteddate;
    }
 }
  {/literal}
</script>


<div id="offDayPopUp" class="offDayDialog" title="Create Event,Commitment,Visiting Area.">
    <div class="CrateDiv">
        <div style="float:left; padding-right:10px;"><b>Date :</b></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="currentDate" id="currentDate" readonly="readonly" /></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="golink('event')"><b>Create A New Event.</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="golink('commitment')"><b>Create A New Commitment.</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="golink('area')"><b>Create A New Visiting Area.</b></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this code...
but it is not working because we can not take onclick event in .tpl file directly. do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: @PrinceBijvani you can very much use onclick in .tpl file. what error are you getting

Comment: @PrinceBijvani try my updated code, if you declaring script inside template file  you need to escape it using literal tag or write script in external js page

Comment: @PrinceBijvani check this link http://jsfiddle.net/zBtNk/1/ , its working. can you be more specific about your problem

Comment: @PrinceBijvani can you paste exact code here. i will try it on my side.